# While using SqlWorkflowPersistenceService get SqlException deadlock in PersistenceDBAccessor.RetrieveNonblockingInstanceStateIds

Tags: workflow-foundation

I'm using WF 3.5 and during the process of spinning up a couple of WorkflowRuntimes, I sometimes get the following exception:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Transaction (Process ID 108) was deadlocked on lock resources with another process and has been chosen as the deadlock victim. Rerun the transaction.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Run(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.HasMoreRows()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.ReadInternal(Boolean setTimeout)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.PersistenceDBAccessor.RetrieveNonblockingInstanceStateIds(Guid ownerId, DateTime ownedUntil)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.SqlWorkflowPersistenceService.RecoverRunningWorkflowInstances()
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.Hosting.SqlWorkflowPersistenceService.OnStarted()
   at System.EventHandler`1.Invoke(Object sender, TEventArgs e)
   at System.Workflow.Runtime.WorkflowRuntime.StartRuntime()
```

I thought running multiple WorkflowRuntimes was ok. I'm spinning up multiples because I'm distributing the work load to different servers, but all are hitting the same database. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer!

I should have used the SqlWorkflowPersistenceService constructor that enables locking:

SqlWorkflowPersistenceService Constructor (String, Boolean, TimeSpan, TimeSpan)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms608171(v=VS.90).aspx

For more information: https://connect.microsoft.com/wf/feedback/details/541240/sqlexception-deadlock-in-persistencedbaccessor-retrievenonblockinginstancestateids